# Register global filters in ASP.Net MVC 4 and Autofac

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, action-filter, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have a filter like this one:

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public MyPropery Property { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I need it to be run for every actions in my project

I tried to register it in the GlobalFilters but my property doesn't get injected

I tried [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108428/1026105) to register my filter but it doesn't get called

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There's a new way of registering MVC global filters in AutoFac. First, **remove** the filter registration from your `RegisterGlobalFilters` because we will have Autofac handle adding them to our controllers/actions instead of MVC.

Then, register your container as follows:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<MyProperty>().As<IProperty>();

builder.Register(c => new CustomFilterAttribute(c.Resolve<IProperty>()))
                .AsActionFilterFor<Controller>().InstancePerHttpRequest();

builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Note that by passing in the `Controller` class into the extension `AsActionFilterFor()` we are telling AutoFac to apply this filter to all classes that derive from the `Controller` class (which, in MVC, is all controllers). Since we are calling `AsActionFilterFor()` without any arguments, we are also specifying we want to have the filter applied to all actions within the specified controllers. If you want to apply your filter to a select controller and action, you can use lambda expressions like so:

```
builder.Register(c => new CustomFilterAttribute(c.Resolve<IProperty>()))
    .AsActionFilterFor<HomeController>(c => c.Index())
    .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

If your action takes a parameter, use the `default` keyword to specify:

```
builder.Register(c => new CustomFilterAttribute(c.Resolve<IProperty>()))
    .AsActionFilterFor<HomeController>(c => c.Detail(default(int)))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

Note that you have to use a different extension method based on what type of filter you are registering, here are the supported filter types:

- AsActionFilterFor
- AsAuthorizationFilterFor
- AsExceptionFilterFor
- AsResultFilterFor

Comment: This bit me so hard! The docs (http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#enable-property-injection-for-action-filters) still mention about property injection, I guess those need to be updated.

Answer (score 17):

You should now use Pete's solution now to do this. Thanks to him for an updated solution.

I finally made it, here is how to do it:

First create your attribute with a constructor with all dependencies

```
public class CustomFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private IProperty _property;

    public CustomFilterAttribute(IProperty repository)
    {
        _property = property;
    }
    ....
 }
```

Register everything you need in autofac

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<MyProperty>().As<IProperty>();
builder.RegisterType<CustomFilterAttribute>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

IContainer container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

Register your global filter like that

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<CustomFilterAttribute>());
}
```

Make sure in your global.asax you register first Autofac and then the global filters.

Now, you don't need property injection anymore, constructor injection will work fine which is a good thing!

Comment: How did you obtain the GlobalFilterCollection filters argument which is needed to invoke the static method in Global.asax?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Never mind, I see the FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters in the Application Start method.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need your dependency scoped to each request.

Comment: @ischell if you want to control the scope, you have to follow this post http://alexmg.com/post/2012/09/01/New-features-in-the-Autofac-MVC-4-and-Web-API-(Beta)-Integrations.aspx

Comment: @Wardy concrete type with a single constructor containing a Interface that needs to be resolved...