# Creating custom FilterAttribute for method parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to create a custom FilterAttribute for incoming parameters?
Mostly attributes are used for methods and classes;

for example my idea is:

`public HttpResponseMessage GetAll([CultureInfo]string culture)`

`{
     if(valid)
     {
          // code here
     }
}`

CultureInfo is a class (CultureInfoAttribute) that inherits from ActionFilterAttribute where i can use 2 methods called, OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting.
On top of my class i used the next attribute so i can use it on parameters:

`[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]`

when i build and i call GetAll("culture") the method OnActionExecuting in my custom filter never gets called....it does when i put the attribute above my method GetAll().

Anyone has expercience with it?

The reason i wanna do this is because i can put attributes on different parameters then instead of the whole method at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346801/register-global-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-autofac):

You should register your filter in `GlobalFilters` in `Global.asax.cs` like this:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new CultureInfoAttribute());
}
```