# Autofac global exception filter throwing null reference exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I'm trying to add a **global** exception handling filter that will log errors in an MVC 5 app.  I need to use Autofac to inject an error logging service into the filter to log the errors.  I have been using Autofac in this app for some time to inject my services and repositories without issue.

When I follow the procedures outlined [here](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/MvcIntegration#Inject_Properties_Into_FilterAttributes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346801/register-global-filters-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-autofac) I am met with a null reference exception:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacFilterProvider.GetFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +206
>   System.Web.Mvc.FilterProviderCollection.GetFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +182
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +37
>   ...

I have removed the global filter registration for this attribute in the global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
        //filters.Add(new HandleExceptionAttribute());
}
```

And setup my Autofac dependency registration:

```
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(BaseService).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.RegisterType<HandleExceptionAttribute>()
    .AsExceptionFilterFor<BaseController>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
```

And my Handle Exception Attribute with constructor injection:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private IErrorLoggingService Service { get; set; }

    public HandleExceptionAttribute(IErrorLoggingService service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        this.Service.LogError(new Error());
    }
}
```

I've done a lot of Googling on this subject but was not able to find an exact example of what I'm looking for.  A few results indicated an issue with also having Glimpse installed, which I had, but since removed.  Calling builder.RegisterFilterProvider(); inside of the Autofac setup is the line that causes the exception.

Am I missing something or is this just not possible?  Does anyone have a working example?  Thanks!

Edit:
I have another global filter applied (AuthorizeAttribute) and I tried removing it but I still get the null ref exception.  Another thought was that I'm using other nuget packages that could cause conflicts, like Glimpse has in the past.
Here are other nuget packages I am using:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AmplifyJS" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angularjs" version="1.2.16" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="CsQuery" version="1.3.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Migrate" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.12.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MicrosoftWebMvc" version="2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MoxieManager" version="1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Mvc2Futures" version="2.0.50217.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcContrib" version="2.0.95.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="PreMailer.Net" version="1.2.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I will try an MVC project from scratch as you suggested to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't reproduce your issue on empty MVC5 project. Make sure you are using correct packages and your code doesn't have any extra wired staff. Here is my solution that works fine.

packages.config:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.3.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.2.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

HandleExceptionAttribute:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    private IErrorLoggingService Service { get; set; }

    public HandleExceptionAttribute(IErrorLoggingService service)
    {
        this.Service = service;
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        this.Service.LogError(filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

IErrorLoggingService:

```
public interface IErrorLoggingService
{
    void LogError(Exception error);
}
```

ErrorLoggingService:

```
public class ErrorLoggingService : IErrorLoggingService
{
    public void LogError(Exception error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

dependencyResolver replacement:

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly)
    .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .PropertiesAutowired();
builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
builder.RegisterType<HandleExceptionAttribute>()
    .AsExceptionFilterFor<BaseController>()
    .InstancePerHttpRequest()
    .PropertiesAutowired();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(builder.Build()));
```

if your solution still doesn't work, try to create an empty project and check if it works fine.

Comment: The problem was related to a part of my Autofac dependency registration that I left out from the original question.  I had set the dependency resolver to a custom DependencyResolver instead of the AutofacDependencyResolver that you listed.  I realized this after your post in the last line of posted code where you set your dependency resolver.  I'd like to thank you again for your help in resolving this issue for me.  I really appreciate it.